# Убрать у функции route редирект c добавление /public в laravel

Tags: php, backend, route, laravel7

Есть такая логика в контроллере -

```
return redirect()
            ->route('blog.admin.order.index.edit', $id)
            ->with(['success' => 'Успешно сохранено']);
```

Все происходит так. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку на сайте, происходит некая логика, которая возвращает ответ с редиректом на эту же страницу, с выводом сообщения.

Возвращает такой url - `https://shop/public/admin/orders/4/edit`. Обычно во всех именованных маршрутах отсутствует `/public`, когда именованные маршруты вставлены в html код.

Как сделать что бы при редиректе не подставлялось `/public`?

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/orders/{order}/edit      | blog.admin.order.index.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Blog\Admin\OrderController@edit                   | web,status,auth |
```

- как выглядит в route:list

Comment: Может сервер неправильно сконфигурирован? `public` - директория с входной точкой.

Comment: DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
    RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Такой код в .htaccess вайле. сам он корневой папке лежит

Comment: Заметил, что проблема появляется из-за того, что есть GET параметр у урла. Т.е. когда используется приставка GET к URL, то только тогда к адресу в начало добавляется /public